# Cordova: How to display splash screen on android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to display splash screen on Android.

But it has not been displayed.

What's wrong?

config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/common/android/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="www/common/android/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="www/common/android/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="www/common/android/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="www/common/android/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="www/common/android/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png" density="xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="www/common/android/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/common/android/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/common/android/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/common/android/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

Version of cordova and plugins

```
$ cordova -v
6.0.0
$ cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.2-dev "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"enter code here
```

Comment: it appears the [splashscreen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) plugin has been upgraded in as many days. Try a [different version](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/releases).

Comment: The problem was resolved in newest viersion. Thanks to your advice.

Comment: Alright. Good to know. Best of Luck.